# Are Cisco access ports basically the same thing as a port on an unmanaged switch?

Tags: cisco, switch, vlan, 802.1

The title should say it all..I'm trying to learn more about VLANs, tagging/trunking, etc.

Comment: Why downvote?  I'm trying to learn isn't that what this site is for?

Comment: Note for anyone finding this closed question: Not quite. Cisco switches are pretty chatty with CDP and STP enabled (default). Moreover STP will prevent the port from going up quickly (<30s) and that can cause issue w/ PXE (dhcp/tftp timeout).

Answer (score 2):

Access ports only receive packets for a single VLAN and the switch can encapsulate received packets and put them in that VLAN. So access ports are not much like unmanaged ports.

Answer (score 2):

Access ports *belonging to the same VLAN* behave like they are on a self-contained switch. That's the very definition of "VLAN".

Consider this scenario:

- A switch has 24 ports
- Ports 1-12 are configured in access mode and assigned to VLAN 10
- Ports 13-24 are configured in access mode and assigned to VLAN 20

From the point of view of connected devices, this behaves exactly as if there were 2 totally unrelated 12-ports switches.